# Do managed CA's use streamwriter differently?

Tags: installation, wix, custom-action, dtf

Has anyone experienced an error in which the custom action's temporary extraction path is appended when creating a file?

I have a managed custom action (64-bit C# DLL using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller)  that performs some system checks.  It writes an inf style key=value file in a deferred CA.  There's really nothing fancy going on here just a File.Create(*FullPathToFile*).

But when I attempt to write the file the temporary directory the CA is extracted to is included for some reason.

> MSI (s) (3C:E4) [10:19:36:712]: Hello, I'm your 64bit Elevated custom action server.
>
> SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIC451.tmp-\
>
> SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v2.0.50727
>
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path ***'C:\Windows Installer\MSIC451.tmp-*C:\Program Files\Path the property file should be written to****'.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>        at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>   at .....

Is there something strange with the way managed CA's use stream writer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that the variable I was trying to use included a property ie:`[TARGETDIR]\otherstuff`.  When I used the variable for as a file path I expected the path `C:\Program Files\productname\otherstuff\mystuff`. But not the property.  When used with some operations (StreamWriter in this case) the property would not resolve properly gave me the error above.

After I figured out that part of the path was actually resolved from a property I was able to make changes to resolve the path I needed from the property and everything works as expected.

`session.Format(Property)` or `session[Property]`